# Having trouble with a SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, select

I'm writing a select statement for some counts.

as such:

```
Select JobType, count(JobType) as count from PrintJobs with (nolock)
where JobType in (1, 2, 3, 4)
and convert(datetime, TimeSubmitted) > cast(CAST(dateadd(dd, -1,GETDATE()) as date)  as datetime) + CAST('17:30:00.000' as time)
group by JobType
```

The problem is that when nothing shows up for the JobTypes the table looks like this

```
JobTypes | count  |
------------------|
    2        1    |
    3        2    |
__________________|
```

Is there a way to make it like this:

```
JobTypes | count  |
------------------|
    1        0    |
    2        1    |
    3        2    |
    4        0    | 
__________________|
```

so that even if there isn't anything in the results for a jobtype it still shows up? I'm trying to make this as dynamic as possible where the jobtypes can be set in a c# sql parameter

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Have you a table with list of JobTypes?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I don't have a table with the job types but I can always create it out of parameters from a user. I'm trying to convert this to a Stored procedure and run it in C#. I'm much more versed in C# than SQL so it's causing some issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is `left join`:

```
Select j.JobType, count(pj.JobType) as count
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) j(jobtype) left join
     PrintJobs pj
     on pj.JobType = j.jobType and
        convert(datetime, TimeSubmitted) > cast(CAST(dateadd(day, -1,GETDATE()) as date)  as datetime) + CAST('17:30:00.000' as time)
group by j.JobType
```

Comment: So far this is the best answer, the only issue is that when the jobtype result is 0 the table I'm getting back shows it as a 1 not 0

Comment: @MatthewSehorn . . . There was a typo.  The correct `count()` is `count(pj.jobtype)`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server like this:

```
Select JTS.JobType, count(*) as count 
from (
   SELECT 1 as JT
     UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as JT
     UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 as JT
     UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 as JT
) AS JTS
LEFT JOIN PrintJobs AS P with (nolock) ON P.JobType = JTS.JT 
      AND convert(datetime, P.TimeSubmitted) > cast(CAST(dateadd(dd, -1,GETDATE()) as date)  as datetime) + CAST('17:30:00.000' as time)
group by P.JobType
```

Here you create a table of the types and join.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with this...the table is blank if the results are blank. Gordon Linoff's answer gives me a table with the job types in it even if the values are 0. The only issue with his is that if the result for a jobtype is 0 his table shows it as a 1

Comment: @MatthewSehorn you need to say the platform --  mine is sql server his is oracle/db2

Comment: @MatthewSehorn -- yes I see the issue change the `WHERE` to an `AND` -- the criteria need to be part of the left join.  See?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select JTypes.JType, count(P.JobType) as count 
 from (
 SELECT 1 as JType
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 as JType
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 as JType
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 as JType
  ) AS JTypes
  LEFT JOIN PrintJobs AS P ON P.JobType = JTypes.JType 
   WHERE  convert(datetime, P.TimeSubmitted) > cast(CAST(dateadd(dd, -1,GETDATE()) as date)  as datetime) + CAST('17:30:00.000' as time)
group by JTypes.JType
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with this...the table is blank if the results are blank. Gordon Linoff's answer gives me a table with the job types in it even if the values are 0. The only issue with his is that if the result for a jobtype is 0 his table shows it as a 1

Comment: @MatthewSehorn when there is no value in PrintJobs table  what is your expected output ?

Comment: 0 would be the answer I'm looking for. If you look at the two example tables in my question the first one shows what I'm currently getting which is only the rows where the printjobs have a count. The second table which is what I'm looking for shows the printjobs as 0 that have 0. Hope that makes sense!